# Special character is not displaying properly

Tags: textarea, special-characters

In a `TextArea`, I am using the `'` character but it is not displaying properly. Instead, it is displaying something like this: `â€“`.

How do I get the `'` character to display properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably not using the Ascii apostrophe (') but some non-Ascii punctuation mark, such as the correct punctuation apostrophe (’). The problem arises because your HTML document is (probably) UTF-8 encoded but the browser interprets it as windows-1252 encoded. If there encoding is not declared in HTTP headers, adding the tag `<meta charset=utf-8>` into the `head` part would help. For general advice on encodings, see the W3C page [Character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php).

The `textarea` element is meant for user input. For presenting your content, other elements (possibly styled with CSS) are usually a better choice. However, the encoding issue is the same.

Comment: I use <meta charset=utf-8>, the other special characters are displaying properly but " ' " is not displaying properly yet

Comment: What you wrote here, " ' ", is not a special character but the Ascii apostrophe. But if you see â€“, then the odds are that you actually have an en dash “–” as UTF-8 encoded but this gets misinterpreted as windows-1252. Maybe your `meta` tag is misplaced, or maybe it is overridden by HTTP headers. Please provide more information, preferably a self-contained document that demonstrates the problem and/or a URL.