# iphone & ipad textarea font doesn't render certain characters

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, textarea, frontend

We've got an app that renders specific font's in a textarea.  Pretty simple.  The problem is that when someone uses an iphone or ipad, apostrophes aren't rendered in the font-family like everything else is.  All the other characters render fine on iphones and ipads, and apostrophes render fine on all web browsers including safari.

Is this a common problem that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Your answer may be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468060/special-character-is-not-displaying-properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Special character is not displaying properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468060/special-character-is-not-displaying-properly)